# Пытаюсь создать p2p сеть но не получается

Tags: python-3.x, многопоточность, сокет

Код:

```
import socket
import argparse
import sys
import threading

args = argparse.ArgumentParser()
#args.add_argument('-a','--addres', help='addres',metavar='')
args.add_argument('-p','--port', help='port',metavar='')
args = args.parse_args()

def server(port):
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), port))
    print("Server started your ip",socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()


    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        conn.send(b'Server',data)

def client():
    connection = input('~ ')
    array = connection.split()
    sock = socket.socket()
    if array[0] == 'connect':
        sock.connect((array[1], args.port))
    else:
        print('Error')
        SystemExit

    sock.send(input('>'))


    data = sock.recv(1024)


p1 = threading.Thread(target=server, name="t1", args=[args.port])   
p2 = threading.Thread(target=client, name="t2")

p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Ошибка:
[image]

а в чем проблема понять не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                                              vvvvvvvv
args.add_argument('-p','--port', help='port', type=int, metavar='')
```

Comment: спасибо большое